# Terraform - Give a subnet name according to its id

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I try to put names to subnets according to its index.
For subnet indexes from 0 to 9, I want to name them sne00 to sne09.
From the tenth subnet, my current code would give me names in sne010. I want to name it sne10.

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "terra_sne" {
  count                = "11"

  # Here, there is the problem
  name                 = count.index == contains(range(1, 11), "") ? "sne${count.index}" : "sne0${count.index}"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.terra_rgo.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.terra_vne.name
  address_prefixes     = [ "172.${var.vnet_octet}.${count.index}.0/24" ]
  service_endpoints    = element(local.subnet_endpoints, count.index)

  dynamic "delegation" {
    for_each = count.index == 8 ? [1] : []

    content {
      name = "aks-delegation"

      service_delegation {
        name    = "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters"
        actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action"]
      }        
    } 
  }
}
```

Terraform plan gives me :

```
# azurerm_subnet.terra_sne[10] will be created
  + resource "azurerm_subnet" "terra_sne" {
      + address_prefixes                               = [
          + "172.28.10.0/24",
        ]
      + enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = (known after apply)
      + enforce_private_link_service_network_policies  = (known after apply)
      + id                                             = (known after apply)
      + name                                           = "sne010"
      + private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled      = (known after apply)
      + private_link_service_network_policies_enabled  = (known after apply)
      + resource_group_name                            = "rgo01"
      + service_endpoints                              = [
          + "Microsoft.Storage",
        ]
      + virtual_network_name                           = "vne01"
    }
```

The name of the subnet to be created is "sne010". I would like "sne10". The name of each subnet should be "if the index is between 0 and 9 then put sne0X otherwise sneXX".

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that can help you understand the `count`on `terraform` and help you solve your issue.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  count                      = 3
  name                       = "Subnet-${count.index}"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name       = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefix            = "10.0.${count.index}.0/24"
}

output "subnet_ids" {
  value = azurerm_subnet.example[*].id
}
```

Comment: The solution in the subnet name is simply this : 
`name = count.index < 10 ? "sne0${count.index}${azurerm_virtual_network.terra_vne.name}" : "sne${count.index}${azurerm_virtual_network.terra_vne.name}"`

Answer (score 0):

Terraform's default way to convert a number to a string is to render it as the minimum number of decimal digits that can represent the number. For example, `9` becomes the string `"9"` and `10` becomes `"10"`.

If you prefer a different string representation of a number then you can use [the `format` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/format) to specify the presentation you want using a mini-language derived from the C language function `printf`.

In your case it seems like your preference is to render a number in decimal but always with at least two digits, using a leading zero for numbers less than 10. In the formatting language, that's written as `%02d`, where:

- `d` means "decimal"
- `2` means to produce at least two characters
- `0` means that any extra leading characters added should be `"0"` (the default is to use spaces)
- `%` is the marker to indicate that the subsequent characters are a formatting command.

Here's how to use that to set your `name` argument:

```
 name = format("sne%02d", count.index)
```

Here are some example results from `terraform console` to illustrate how that behaves:

```
> format("sne%02d", 0)
"sne00"
> format("sne%02d", 1)
"sne01"
> format("sne%02d", 2)
"sne02"
> format("sne%02d", 9)
"sne09"
> format("sne%02d", 10)
"sne10"
> format("sne%02d", 100)
"sne100"
```

Notice that if you ever have enough instances to reach index 100 then it'll start needing more than two digits and so no longer be "aligned" in the same way, but as long as you always have 100 or fewer instances it will always use two digits.

---

**Bonus chatter**, not directly related to your question:

I notice you're also using string interpolation to construct an IP address. That's okay in your case because you're setting entire octets and the standard IP address format is for each octet to be written as decimal digits with no padding, but there's a different way to do it which makes Terraform calculate the CIDR prefix using arithmetic with binary numbers and therefore isn't constrained by using only entire octets, using [the `cidrsubnet` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/cidrsubnet):

```
address_prefixes = [
  cidrsubnet(
    cidrsubnet("172.0.0.0/8", 8, var.vnet_octet),
    8, count.index,
  )
]
```

The above uses two calls to `cidrsubnet`, one nested inside the other, to deal with your two subnet operations:

1. `Extend 172.0.0.0/8` into a `/16` prefix using the `var.vnet_octet` value to populate the next eight bits.
2. `Extend that /16` prefix into a `/24` prefix using the `count.index` value to populate the next eight bits.

As long as you are always adding new values eight bits (one octet) at a time there's no real difference to how you were doing it, but with this approach you can potentially make more efficient use of your IP address numbering space by using shorter extensions. For example, if you expect that you will never have more than 16 subnets declared by this resource, you could change the outermost `cidrsubnet` call to use `4` as the number of new bits, instead of 8, because four bits is enough to store all values from 0 to 15. Your subnet CIDR prefix would then be a `/20` prefix instead of a `/24`, giving you 4096 IP addresses per subnet instead of only 255.

None of what I wrote in this sidebar is important to your original question, so feel free to ignore it if you're happy using 8 bits per subnet level! I mention it only because using `cidrsubnet` is the more typical way to build subnet prefixes in Terraform, rather than using string concatenation.